# Прошу помочь решить простейшую задачу с Codewar на замену символов в строке Python

Tags: python, строки, замена

Задача: убрать в строке все пробелы и заменить все символы кроме последних четырёх на "#".

Код:

```
cc = input('Enter your string please: ')
cc = cc.replace(' ', '')
for char in cc[:-4]:
    cc = cc.replace(char,'#')
print(cc)
```

Проблема:

Для строки до 16 символов включительно (после  `cc = cc.replace(' ', '')`) программа работает корректно. Если символов больше, то начинаются не запрограммированные чудеса: замена символов на знак "#" идёт по своему сценарию.

Предполагаю, что дело в цикле for, но не могу найти причину.

Comment: Вместо цикла: res = '#' * (len(cc) - 4) + cc[-4:]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим такую строку: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

Что с ней сделает ваш цикл?

```
for char in cc[:-4]:
    cc = cc.replace(char,'#')
```

На первой итерации он берёт первый символ 'a', и заменяет ВСЕ символы 'a' в строке на '#'. И в том числе последние четыре тоже.

То есть некорректный результат ваш код будет выдавать для любой строки, где хотя бы один из четырёх последних символов встречается до этого в строке.

Ну а как делать правильно, вам уже написал в комментарии MaxU.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не всё понял, но буду разбираться)